# No query registered for []

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to add `missing` filter to ES query `bool`.
I tried to add directly to `bool` and I got `no query registered for [missing]`.
Then I added `filter` and got `no query registered for [filter]`.

I see many StackOverflow questions, and in many this works.
Query example:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
            "missing": {
                "field": "firstname"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

ES version 1.5.2

Comment: Is that your complete query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like missing filter is being removed in elastic 5.x. I was told not to use it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/query-dsl-exists-query.html#_literal_missing_literal_query

Do this instead

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "firstname"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```